# Insert JSON as class gone from VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

maybe I'm being stupid but why the hell is the Visual Studio 2017 option Edit>Paste Special>Insert JSON as class gone? I still have the XML option but JSON is gone?

Must've disappeared with an update? Why?

Comment: I still have it there. Actually it also depends on which file is open when you try to find that option. Make sure a .cs file is open when you try to find that option. Also, if that doesn't work out, you can always use websites like http://json2csharp.com

Comment: I still have it as well. Which VS edition and version have you got installed? I've got VS Enterprise 2017 Version 15.5.6

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it's a feature of ASP.NET, gotta make sure you're in an ASP.NET project